# Java 2D ImageIO.Write hindering performance

Tags: java, image, performance, 2d, javax.imageio

I maintain a Java application that generates A LOT of widgets (I say widget because it will generate PDF's or PNG Files - to disk). The application was designed to generate PDF's and later images became a requirement.

My transactions per second (TPS) are suffering when generating images. The basic flow is that I create a BufferedImage and Graphics2D instances. Use the Graphics2D object to drawn some text. I pull in a few other images to add to my new image. Then I write the BufferedImage to to an OutputStream.

I have honed in on the ImageIO.write() method as a possible culprit. The application is RESTful and a whole transaction can take... lets say 500ms. I have clocked the ImageIO.write() method to take up at least 80-90% of that transaction time.

```
ImageIO.write(image,"PNG",os);  // 420ms !!!!
```

I am having a difficult time finding a way around ImageIO.write()... Any suggestions are appreciated.

Notes: Images are RGB ColorModel && end up around 50kb. I have seen better performance with Binary color model, but color is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Just to back up jonwilks' link to ObjectPlanet's "[PngEncoder](http://objectplanet.com/pngencoder/)" - we tested it and had similar results, roughly 30-50% improvement over ImageIO.write which is pretty awesome - and it's free when you use the binary only. Recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I too have seen, that ImageIO on PNG is slow, JPEG faster, but I consider PNG better for text.

You could try [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/index.html). Also one may maintain the ImageIO API, as that can deal with several providers for writing/reading an image mime type.

One thing I did not try, but might help, set the cache directory to a fast RAM disk: `ImageIO.setCacheDirectory(ramdisk)`, or `setUseCache(false)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response I was unaware of those settings and will look into the further. I however did find a third party encoder to try today.

http://objectplanet.com/pngencoder/

I have done a few test, here are my real world results. Which are better than ImageIO… but I am still on the hunt for a better solution. 

ImageIO - Write Time PNG: 544 ms.
ImageIO - Write Time JPG: 76 ms.
ImageIO - Write Time JPG: 751 ms.
OPPngEncoder - Write Time PNG: 208 ms.